# Write to the samba docker container from iOS/Mac fails with attribute not found

Tags: linux, docker, samba

I use a dperson/samba container and when I try to write to the samba server from iOS/Mac it doesn't let me and tells me that it hasn't found the attribute but on Windows it lets me write

```
samba:
    image: dperson/samba:latest
    container_name: samba
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 139:139
      - 445:445
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid:/etc/localtime
      - /mnt/VÍDEO/nube:/nube
    command: '-u "Jose;password" -s "LaNube;/nube;yes;no;no;Jose;;;" -p'
```

The text is in Spanish but says Attribute not found

[image: THE IMAGE IS IN SPANISH BUT THE TEXT SAYS ATTRIBUTE NOT FOUND]

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you see, possibly as a screenshot.

Comment: @DanielB i Edit WITH a imagen os in Spanish but the TEXT says ATTRIBUTE NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

I have dperson/samba also, and I want to share my config if that helps:

```
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: samba
    hostname: samba
    cpu_percent: 50
    mem_limit: 150m
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
      - RECYCLE=False
      - NMBD=True
      - WORKGROUP=HOME
      - WIDELINKS=True
      - USERID=1000
      - GROUPID=1000
    networks:
      - internal-lan
      - external
    ports:
      - 137:137/udp
      - 138:138/udp
      - 139:139
      - 445:445
    volumes:
      - ./external_hdd/samba:/shared_folder:rw
    command: '-u "username_ssh_user;password_ssh_user_server" -s "shared_folder;/shared_folder;yes;no;yes" -p'
```

You must change values `username_ssh_user` and `password_ssh_user_server` with the user then launch that docker.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `dperson/samba` on the OSX host? And I see you use `bind mount`:

```yml
volumes:
      - /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid:/etc/localtime
      - /mnt/VÍDEO/nube:/nube
```

It's recommended to use `volume mount` instead of `bind mount`, because Mac Docker runs in a light Linux VM, and Mac host used different filesystem(HFS+) compared with Linux(ext4).

The `volume mount` is like:

```yml
volumes:
      - Madrid:/etc/localtime
      - nube:/nube
```